# How to see commit message from docker images

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and begin playing with it.
I have created a few images from committing a few changes.
Started with

```
sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

doing a few installs, exited and did

```
sudo docker commit -m="my first message" innocent_dockernovice sandbox/yves:s1
```

and repeting the process

```
sudo docker run -i -t sandbox/yves:sN /bin/bash
```

doing stuff in shells, exiting and

```
sudo docker commit -m="what I did in step N" happy_dockeruser sandbox/yves:sN+1
```

Now I want to go back to a previous step image and would like to list all the messages doing a `sudo docker image -m` kind of command similar to a `git log` one. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: You might look into adding your account to the list of docker users. So you don't need to keep typing sudo. https://gist.github.com/aluedeke/7977839#file-gistfile1-sh

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the tip. I can not manage to get myself properly in the docker group. ran from root : `gpasswd yves docker`. `/etc/group` is correctly modified but when under my account I run a `docker ps -a` I get `Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.12/containers/json?all=1: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied`

Comment: I've used `sudo gpasswd -a USER docker`  # replace USER with your user name on Ubuntu14.04 and it works for me. You have to also `sudo service docker restart`. You might also try restarting the system and see if that helps.

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 for me to but I must have something broken with groups as what you did do not work in my case...

Comment: I just retested this on a fresh vagrant box. I had to **restart** to make this take effect. Also I had to do `sudo service docker.io restart`. I forgot I soft linked docker.io to docker on my previous system. https://gist.github.com/icecreammatt/f2dfaf34226b47d015da Hopefully this helps.

Comment: restarting was the missing part on my side and yes I had restarted docker.io before. All works fine now, thanks for your time.

Comment: @YvesNicolas I would advise to not install docker from the Ubuntu packages as the docker.io package is outdated (v0.9.1 for trusty, while latest docker is v1.2.0). Install docker with `curl -sSL https://get.docker.io/ubuntu/ | sudo sh` as described at https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can view commit messages by using docker inspect on the commit hash displayed afterwards. To view more of them you must do it recursively.

```
$ docker commit -m "added test file" sick_morse
61efdbd141dc5fb1c289ed5151f3ce7b5985a5829bd92ba322ad6061cb1eee21
$ docker inspect 61efdbd141dc5fb1c289ed5151f3ce7b5985a5829bd92ba322ad6061cb1eee21 | grep added
    "Comment": "added test file",
```

Found info [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/Z0MbPaeD_7I)

This would let you view the messages for the top 3 most recent comments.

```
$ docker images -a --no-trunc | head -n4 | grep -v "IMAGE ID" | awk '{ print $3 }' | xargs docker inspect | grep Comment
```

Comment: otherwise, `docker inspect 61efdbd141dc5fb1c289ed5151f3ce7b5985a5829bd92ba322ad6061cb1eee21 | jq -r 'map(.Id+" "+.Comment)[]'`

Answer (score 18):

To make things simple, i did a simple bash script in github gist: [docker-log](https://gist.github.com/yarcowang/370e63e68972afbff970)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DOCKER=`which docker`

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 IMAGE"
  exit 0
fi

for commit in $($DOCKER history $1 | sed 1d | awk '{ print $1 }')
do
  content="$commit
$($DOCKER inspect $commit | tr -d '\"' | grep 'Created\|Author\|Comment')"
  echo "$content"
done
```

Snapshot for usage:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that.  But just to be clear: there's no built-in way to list a docker image's commits ?!

Answer (score 14):

You can use docker history command:

```
$ docker history <image hash>
```

Sample output:

```
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY        SIZE          COMMENT
02c473b152e3        9 days ago          /bin/bash         1.577 kB      modified init.sh
39a27fe266c4        9 days ago          /bin/bash         1.472 kB      modified init.sh
1a8dae63b9fe        9 days ago          /bin/bash         1.457 kB      modified init.sh
```

Comment: When I do `docker history <image hash>`, I don't get the COMMENT column. I wonder why that is.

Comment: Is this a new feature? It works for me, is one line, seems to answer the question, and only uses my (I think standard) docker installation... but it only had one vote.

Comment: This feature has been there for a while.

Comment: Most easy and straightforward solution.